# Find minimum number 1's so the matrix consist of 1 connected region of 1's

Tags: algorithms, graphs, matrices

Let $M$ be a $(0, 1)$ matrix. We say two entries are neighbors if they are adjacent horizontal or vertically, and both entries are $1$'s. One wants to find minimum number of $1$'s to add, so every $1$ can reach another one through a sequence of neighbors.

Example:

```
100
000
001
```

Here we need 3 $1$'s:

```
100
100
111
```

How can we efficiently find the minimum number of $1$'s to add, and where?

Comment: It is often helpful to cast a problem as a problem of another type; for example this time a matrix problem as a graph problem. This gives you all the tools of graph theory to work with. At first sight, your problem seemed like a shortest path problem to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you model your problem with graphs, Your problem is like [Steiner Tree problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem):

See [here](http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Compgeometry/MyCG/CG-Applets/SteinerTree/msteinercli.htm) for simplest possible definition.

> Given a weighted graph in which a subset of vertices are identified as
>   terminals, find a minimum-weight connected subgraph that includes all
>   the terminals.

As you can see it's NPC in general, but in your case your graph is grid graph, may be you can find good solution for it, but for your current example (when terminals are in boundary) you can see [Steiner tree in grid graphs paper](http://www.cs.ou.edu/~thulasi/Misc2/steiner_trees_grid_graph.pdf).

Anyway there are excellent heuristics for Steiner Tree problem, you can apply similar approach to your problem.

P.S: You can assume neighbor 1s are connected nodes, after that you can contract their edges to make a new graph, your new created graph is planar, and if you could solve the Steiner Tree for it you can solve your problem, but may be there is a good solution for your problem which is independent from Steiner Tree.

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, the problem remains NP-complete even if edges have unit weight.

Comment: @mrm, Yes, actually wikipedia link, says about unweighted version (implicitly) See [its generalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem#Generalization_of_minimum_spanning_tree). I thought that may be wiki link is not clear in first glance, So I quoted a simple definition.

Comment: Also note that not all 1's have to be on the boundary of the matrix in order to be on the boundary of the resulting grid-graph

Comment: You seem to be reducing OP's problem to Stiener Tree, which says that Stiener Tree is at least as hard as OP's problem. Not the other way round: i.e. the first sentence is misleading. Of course, the wiki page you linked, also talks about the Rectilinear Stiener Tree problem, which seems to be quite relevant.

Comment: @Aryabhata, No I didn't do any reduction, just some format of OPs problem is exactly same as Stiener Tree problem, So it's at least as hard as Stiener Tree, but as I mentioned that, OPs problem works on grids, and if Stiener Tree is solvable on grids, he can do this for his problem, but Rectilinear case is harder than grids, in fact, grids are special case of Rectilinear graphs, so I suggested a paper for grid graphs, which can solve special case in grids in $P$, In all I never said that his problem is NPC or something like this, and if you think I said this please tell me to delete it.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: What does at least as hard as Stiener Tree really mean then?

Comment: @Aryabhata, If you model this problem with graph it will be at least as hard as finding steiner tree in related graph, but Steiner Tree is proven to be NP-Hard in some cases not all special cases. I don't know how to express it better. I see my answer is longer than putting comment, actually my answer is just motivation, I don't know how to solve OPs problem or showing its NP-Hardness.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: By modelling it as a graph problem, and finding Stienier Tree, you have done a reduction to Stiener tree haven't you? Saying that it is at least as hard as Stiener tree is misleading. You could model it as graph and still have fast algorithms without trying to run the general Stiener tree (as you yourself noted) algorithm. All I am saying is that the first sentence is misleading/inaccurate and should be edited.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3129/discussion-between-saeed-amiri-and-aryabhata)

Comment: I had thought the problem might have a NP-hard flavor, so it is indeed the case.